# Elastic Search Partial Update

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do a partial update like below . Add some new fields like Bytes_In and Bytes_Out. And also run a script to update a field that is derived from other fields using a script.

Script session-duration-script.groovy is under /config/scripts path.

```
ctx._source.duration= (new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",ctx._source.sessionTerminationDateTime.replace("T", " ").substring(0,23)).getTime() - new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",ctx._source.eventConversionDateTime.replace("T", " ").substring(0,23)).getTime())


access/access-event-logs/session-summary/0a30fd59karabip1new.lab.fp.f5net.com/_update   
{
       "doc" : {
          "active" : false,
          "Bytes_In": "100",
          "Bytes_Out": "100",
          "sessionTerminationDateTime": "2015-10-30T02:50:39.237Z"
       },
       "script_fields": {
               "my_field": {
                   "script_file": "session-duration-script"
                 }
        }
    }
```

When i run the above update query ,I get this error

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "status:400, body:{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"action_request_validation_exception\",\"reason\":\"Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both script and doc;\"}],\"type\":\"action_request_validation_exception\",\"reason\":\"Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both script and doc;\"},\"status\":400}",
  "originalRequestBody": "{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"action_request_validation_exception\",\"reason\":\"Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both script and doc;\"}],\"type\":\"action_request_validation_exception\",\"reason\":\"Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both script and doc;\"},\"status\":400}",
  "referer": "172.17.86.67",
  "restOperationId": 6555035,
  "kind": ":resterrorresponse"
}
```

Please let me know of there is way to achieve this kind of update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you cannot use both `doc` and `script`. My suggestion is modifying the script to also add the fields you want, and pass the values of these fields using the `params` map.

Answer (score 0):

To [update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) a document, you can either provide a `doc` **or** a `script`. Also you can't use `script_fields` like this.

Change your `session-duration-script.groovy` to this

**EDIT** : If you want `duration` to be calculated based on new `sessionTerminationDateTime` then put the first line at the end (Thanks to @Val)

```
ctx._source.duration= (new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",ctx._source.sessionTerminationDateTime.replace("T", " ").substring(0,23)).getTime() - new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",ctx._source.eventConversionDateTime.replace("T", " ").substring(0,23)).getTime());
ctx._source.active = active;
ctx._source.Bytes_In = Bytes_In; 
ctx._source.Bytes_Out = Bytes_Out;
ctx._source.sessionTerminationDateTime = sessionTerminationDateTime;
```

After that, this is how you can update the doc

```
POST access-event-logs/session-summary/0a30fd59karabip1new.lab.fp.f5net.com/_update
{
  "script": {
    "file": "session-duration-script",
    "params": {
      "active": false,
      "Bytes_In": "100",
      "Bytes_Out": "100",
      "sessionTerminationDateTime": "2015-10-30T02:50:39.237Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to set the `ctx._source.sessionTerminationDateTime` variable **before** computing `ctx._source.duration`, i.e. move the fifth line of the script to the first position, since the computation of the duration uses that value.

Comment: Thanks @Val, did not realize `duration` is using that particular field, I will edit the answer