# How to insert new or update old document using elasticsearch-py?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

What is the most elegant way to insert a new document (if not already exists) or update (increase counter by 1) of an already existed document?

This one:

```
res = elasticsearch.update(
        index='stories-test',
        doc_type='news',
        id=1,
        body={
            "doc":
                {
                    "author": "me",
                    "visits": 1
                },
                'doc_as_upsert': True
        },
        script={
                    "inline": "ctx._source.visits += visit",
                    "params": {
                        "visit": 1
                    }
        }
    )
```

Troughs the following error:

```
RequestError: TransportError(400, u'action_request_validation_exception', u"Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both script and doc;")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include `"doc"` field in the body to update.

```py
es = Elasticsearch()
doc = NewsSerializer(news).data
es.update(index="news_index", doc_type='news', id=1, body={"doc": doc})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the update query with both doc and script params. You can do all the stuff in the `script` field using the `params` field in it.

You may find more information in this post:

[Elastic Search Partial Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666720/elastic-search-partial-update)